# AWS Amplify: warning async-storage@0.1.0: The engine "firefox" appears to be invalid

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage, aws-amplify

I am making an application on React Native and I have linked AWS authentication to my app.

However, every time I run:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

the following errors come up:

```
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
warning async-storage@0.1.0: The engine "firefox" appears to be invalid.
warning async-storage@0.1.0: The engine "fennec" appears to be invalid.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > aws-amplify-react-native@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
```

as a result my `yarn start` tells me this:

```
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:42.823]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:44.496]  ERROR    Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:44.502]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/PubSub.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:44.504]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/util.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/types.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/util.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:44.506]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js -> node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/withSSRContext.js -> node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:44.507]  LOG      Running "MusicApp" with {"rootTag":11,"initialProps":{}}
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:48.519]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:49.897]  ERROR    Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:49.899]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/PubSub.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:49.900]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/util.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/types.js -> node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/util.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:49.901]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js -> node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/withSSRContext.js -> node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:04:49.902]  LOG      Running "MusicApp" with {"rootTag":21,"initialProps":{}}
[Mon Feb 15 2021 13:05:33.564]  ERROR    Warning: Picker has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-picker 
PhoneField@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:393227:22
RCTView
RCTScrollContentView
RCTScrollView
ScrollView@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:63793:36
ScrollView
TouchableWithoutFeedback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:69917:36
Wrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:393381:81
SignUp@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:396483:22
RCTSafeAreaView
SafeAreaView
Container@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:393195:22
Authenticator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:394078:22
Wrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:393668:24
RCTView
RCTView
AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:67628:22
```

I was hoping if anyone has a solution for this!!